# PHP, XML correcto para request a SOAP webservice

Tags: php, xml, soapui

disculpen tengo una URL de tipo WSDL para conectarme a un WebService de tipo SOAP, el webservice tiene un método para crear ventas, donde me solicita enviar como parámetros la siguiente estructura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GenerarVenta xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <venta>
        <VentaDT>
          <Encabezado>
            <FechaEntrega>2019-08-22 2:20:00</FechaEntrega>
            <Amex type="xs:decimal">0</Amex>
            <Tarjeta type="xs:decimal">899.00</Tarjeta>
          </Encabezado>
          <Cuerpo>
            <Producto_Id>013059</Producto_Id>
            <Cantidad type="xs:decimal">1</Cantidad>
            <Precio type="xs:decimal">899.00</Precio>
          </Cuerpo>
        </VentaDT>    
      </venta>
    </GenerarVenta>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Pero con esta estructura obtengo un error: 
*Error:El argumento 'column' no puede ser nulo.
Nombre del parámetro: column*

Este es mi código PHP

```
$wsdl = "http://irusalserver.dns-dns.com/eComerce/Servicio.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, 
    array(
        'trace' => 1, 
        "cache_wsdl" => 0, 
        "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_1
    )
);
$encabezado = array();
$encabezado[] = new SoapVar("2019-08-27T12:20:00",XSD_DATETIME,'datetime','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','FechaEntrega');
$encabezado[] = new SoapVar(0,XSD_DECIMAL,'decimal','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','Amex');
$encabezado[] = new SoapVar(899.00, XSD_DECIMAL, 'decimal', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'Tarjeta' );
$BigEncabezado = new SoapVar($encabezado,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'Encabezado');

$cuerpo=array();
$cuerpo[]=new SoapVar("013059",XSD_STRING,'string','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','Producto_Id');
$cuerpo[]=new SoapVar(1.00,XSD_DECIMAL,'decimal','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','Cantidad');
$cuerpo[]=new SoapVar(899.00,XSD_DECIMAL,'decimal','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','Precio');
$BigCuerpo=new SoapVar($cuerpo,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'Cuerpo');

    $FF = array($BigEncabezado,$BigCuerpo);

    $FlexFields = new SoapVar($FF,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'venta');
    $resp = $client->GenerarVenta(
        array('venta'=>$FlexFields)
    );

    pr($resp);
```

Pero me da error: El campo Cantidad de la columna Cuerpo es BDNull, he tratado de mandarlo como entero y como decimal, pero sale el mismo error como si no reconociera el valor de Cantidad.

El método que quiero llamar es: **GenerarVenta**, primero trato de generar la estructura correcta del XML para probarlo en SoapUI y si funciona despues hacerlo con PHP.

Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar por favor.
Gracias.

Comment: Queda pendiente ver el código con el que intentas consumir ese WS

Comment: Recuerda que toda info adicional la puedes añadir editando tu pregunta. En lo posible, como texto (para que todos podamos leer y replicar más fácil tu problema)

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, gracias, ya edite mi pregunta y agregué mi código PHP, como es mi primer vez con webservice, trato de probar ese método utilizando el programa SoapUI, donde mando la request en un XML y recibo la respuesta, intento crear el XML correcto para despues pasarlo a PHP.